# Database Parent-Child Relationship

Tags: mysql, oracle, erd

Can a parent table be a child table of its child table?

For example, if there are only two tables that are linked so one is parent, and another one is child. Can the parent table be a child table and vice versa?

Answer (score 0):

Yes.

Say you have classes and teachers.

Teacher table can have a ClassID; Class can have a TeacherID. It may / may not make any sense depending on the model, but on the database level it's certainly possible.

Answer (score 0):

It's like you want, so yes you can : you'll have to use join and alias to get back your data properly.

If you only get a `A-B-A` relationship it's OK, but be careful with recursive relationship when you don't have a fixed deep as, it's a big pain to get back everything on a single query (take a look a the Tree pattern and other specific DB structure, it can be a better choice).

Comment: @JonathanNelsonCastillo what do you really want to do ? if it's basic stuff I think `JOIN` and alias will be enough for your case